# Relations, Eloquent and Joins

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

Lets say I have 2 Tables:

Pages [id, parent_id, content]
Comments [id, page_id, content]

When I'm viewing a page I want to display all comments for that page PLUS comments for pages that have this page as parent.

```
class Comment extends Eloquent
{
    protected $table = "comments";

    public function page()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Page','page_id','id');
    }
}

class Page extends Eloquent
{
    protected $table = "pages";

    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->has_many('Comment');
    }
}

$comments = new Comment();
$comments= $comments->where('page_id',$id)->with('page')->get();
```

I need comments for the current page, pages that have the current page as parent and I want all the data from the pages table to come along with the comments so I could print out the page_id/title whatever next to each comment.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but it theory Laravel should parse nested relations like so:

```
Page::where('page_id',$id)->with('comments','parent.comments')->get();
```

That's assuming you have a 'parent' relationship on the Page model.

```
public function parent()
{
    return $this->hasOne('Page','parent_id');
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this has got me a closer, but I would like the comments to be in the same object so I could get latest comment for the current page or subpage combined. Right now when I use ->latest() it get's the latest of both (main page and child pages).

Comment: Then I would suggest you introduce a separate class that unifies all the comment objects and returns them in a Collection object (so that you can call latest() etc). You can do it using a recursive traversal of the collection (essentially going over ALL objects in the collection, irrespctive of depth of nesting, and check if it is an instanceof Comment) returned by the query i showed you. A good example can be seen here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14245392/recursive-traversal-of-object